# Can't launch Android project from green Run icon

Tags: android, eclipse

This always worked before but since yesterday the little green arrow (green background, white right pointing triangle) does not work. Nothing happens, except maybe once in twenty tries. I have to push the small black down facing triangle right to it and launch the project from the popup menu.

I also have a keyboard shortcut bound to the same "Run" command. Also this shortcut has the same problem. It only rare works since yesterday. Most of the times there's nothing happening at all. No output in Console.

Comment: Not sure whether is this the case or not. When you working on your XML or Manifest and you launch your application it wont really work. It will launch your xml file instead and might create an extra file in your project. Try to launch your application in an activity(Java) page.

Comment: Any chance you unchecked project --> automatically build? I had to do this for an export crash issue, but it causes run problems if not checked again afterward.

Comment: Isaac: I think you're right. When working on XML files, it doesn't work. Seems to work when working on .java files. However, I'll almost swear that it did work until yesterday. Maybe it shouldn't work by design, and the Eclipse devs "fixed" it. :-(
As for me, I don't give a ... if I'm working on the design or the logic. When I say run, I mean run :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether is this the case or not. When you working on your XML or Manifest and you launch your application it wont really work. It will launch your xml file instead and might create an extra file in your project. Try to launch your application in an activity(Java) page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Clean Project -> close all files
2. Restart Eclipse
3. Right click on project -> Run As -> Android Application
4. Try the run button again.
   Let us know the outcome.